# Passing CGI command line parameters to a PHP file

Tags: php, parameters, cgi

A company is sending info to my site and they want to send it to a CGI file as:

`mysite.com/cgi-bin/process.cgi?custid=ab123&amount=12345`

I have to write the parameter data to a MySql db and I'd rather use PHP (since I don't know cgi). How can I pass the url parameters to my php script? Also, if I redirect to a php file, would the sender know that I was doing that? Can't I just "call" the php file from the cgi script?

Comment: PHP is CGI, so you know CGI already. See http://php.net/install.unix.commandline.php - it's probably like you know and likely that they said CGI just to make clear they want some script on the server probably.

Comment: IMO, be up front with your client.  Make sure you're speaking the same language.

Answer (score 3):

To run PHP script as CGI you need to know these

1. As CGI PHP will not run as a apache handler, rather run as a process.
2. PHP will not populate `$_GET` or `$_POST`,
3. Your php file should be executable `chmod +x`
4. The shebang line should be `#!/usr/bin/env php` or `#!/usr/bin/php`
5. GET data should be read from QUERY_STRING and POST, PUT should be read from STDIN.
6. HTTP headers should be sent **manually**.

So your `process.cgi` will look something like this,

```
#!/usr/bin/env php-cli
<?php
// populating $_GET
$_GET=parse_str(getenv('QUERY_STRING'));
$custid=$_GET['custid'];
$amount = $_GET['amount'];
// do work

echo "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
echo "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
// start output here.
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `parse_str` without a second parameter to store the result of the parse is deprecated in PHP 7.2.0 (http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). The function does not return a value now. You can pull the query string from `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, so the `parse_str` call becomes `parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $destination)`, like this:

```
<?php
$DEBUG = true;
if ($DEBUG) echo "<p>PHP: good to go</p>";
if ($DEBUG) echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);
if (empty($_GET)) {
    if ($DEBUG) echo "<p>Not picking up the GET.</p>";
    exit;
}
if ($DEBUG) echo "<p>Got a GET.</p>";
if ($DEBUG) print_r($_GET);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a normal PHP script to process the data they pass (using the `$_GET` variables), and setup a .htaccess redirect to mask the fact that it's not handled by an actual CGI script.

Just put this in a .htaccess file in the site root, alongside the PHP script (called "process.php" in this example).

```
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/process.cgi$ process.php [L]
```

You could run the PHP script through a CGI script, but it just adds more complexity. Keep it simple.